# PHP Update Query not working for profile pic

Tags: php, sql, database, mysqli

I have this code and it gives my a Error 500. I am trying to make it so that it will change the profile picture.

```
<?php
include_once("dbConnect.php");
include_once("indexinfo.php");
$_POST['username'] = $usname;
$_POST['imagelink'] = $image;
$dbCon = mysqli_connect("DATABASE STUFFS");
if(isset($_POST['imagelink'])) {
    $imagelink = "SELECT `username` UPDATE `TEST` SET `picture` = '$_POST['imagelink']' WHERE username = '$_SESSION['username']'";
    mysqli_query($dbCon, $imagelink);
}
?>
```

Comment: where are `$usname` and `$image` defined?

Comment: wheres dbConnect and indexinfo?

Comment: any lines called out with an error?

Comment: where do $usname and image come from

Comment: The if statement is not working!

Answer (score -1):

Assuming `$usname` and `$image` are already defined, use them directly (without assigning `$_POST`) and change the update-query line to the following:

```
$imagelink = "UPDATE `TEST` SET `picture` = '$image' WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'";
```

Notice no SELECT clause and use of curly braces.

Also check [mysqli_error](https://www.php.net/mysqli_error) for possible database errors after your query.